# Target specific list items and enter text via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I target all "Level 3" and "Level 4" links and enter a dash before the text that is displayed for the link?

e.g So from the code below, anything that says something like "Level 3 Page 1" or "Level 4 Page 1" will now say "- Level 3 Page 1"

This is what's generated by Wordpress (so I can't just enter a dash into the link):

```
<ul>
    <li class="top-level"><a href="#">Extra Curriculum</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-42"><a href="#">Level 2 Page 1</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item page-item-51">
        <a href="#">Level 3 Page 1</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-56"><a href="#/">Level 4 Page 1</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-57"><a href="#">Level 4 Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-59"><a href="#">Level 4 Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-52"><a href="#">Level 3 Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-54"><a href="#">Level 3 Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-44"><a href="#">Level 2 Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-47"><a href="#">Level 2 Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm guessing this is a job for jquery?

Comment: Can you use CSS `list-style`?

Comment: @dfsq I don't think you can put in a dash can you???

Comment: Not with list-style (you could only use an image to get the “dash”) – but you can use generated content using `:before` and `content:"–"`. And targeting these LI should be easy as well, using the descendant selector, so something like `ul li ul li {…}`

Comment: @Rob Right seems like you can't. I would use `.children li a:before {content: '-'}`. http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/ax6N3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this help

```
$('ul .children a').each(function() {
$(this).text("- "+$(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a:contains(Level 3),a:contains(Level 4)").each(function() {
    $(this).text("- "+$(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
li.level3, li.level4
{
   background-position: left;
   background-image : "url(dash.jpeg)";
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery code:**

```
$('a:contains(Level 3), a:contains(Level 4)').prepend('-');
```

Link to: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hjUxU/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:before` pseudo-element:

```
.children > li:before {
  content: "-";
}
```